# Fastreport: how to make Header+MasterData+Footer together?

Tags: header, footer, fastreport

I have a PageHeader and a MasterData with Header .. Next Header+MasterData+Footer.
I want to Keep Header+MasterData+Footer all together if they don’t fit in the page.

I mean, when they don’t fit in the page they move to the next Page.

I Tried KeepTogether propriety of the MasterData , but all it did is move 1 line of data to the next page.

The Height of the MasterData changes depends on nbr of line in MemoView
so I can’t know the Height of MasterData in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try turning off the AllowSplit Property for the master data.
The KeepTogether just makes sure that the footer is attached to the bottom of the master data, without considering where the rest of the master data is.
You will probably want to set a max amount for the MasterData, otherwise if the three data bands don't fit on a single page a problem can occur.  I crashed my program once when it tried adding a new page until it fit, which it never did and made a zillion empty pages.